# Arduino MCP23S17 I/O Expander (SPI)

Tags: arduino-uno, pins

I found this [post](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/14191/mcp23s17-programming-iodirx-register-works-in-loop-but-not-in-setup) and I am having almost the exact same issue. Nick Gammon (the god of arduino) has an excellent answer but I can't for the life of me implement it myself. I am not an advanced user like the initial question asker.

So What I want to do is use 2 MCP23S17's ([picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZman.jpg)).
I have been messing with one of them all week and have it reading like a charm. I am using the [githib library](https://github.com/n0mjs710/MCP23S17) by n0mjs710 to do this. But writing to one will not work.

Along with the zipped library is a few examples. I am trying to read some BCD switches off of one "input MCP" and then display the digits on the "output MCP"

I have used external pullups so I did make one change to the code by commenting out the call for pullups. Here is what Doesn't work:

```
#include <SPI.h>              // We use this library, so it must be called here.
#include <MCP23S17.h>         // Here is the new class to make using the MCP23S17 easy.

MCP inputchip(1, 10);             // Instantiate an object called "inputchip" on an MCP23S17 device at address 1
                                  // and slave-select on Arduino pin 10
MCP outputchip(2, 10);            // Instantiate an object called "outputchip" on an MCP23S17 device at address 2
                                  // and slave-select on Arduino pin 10

void setup() {
  inputchip.begin();
  outputchip.begin();
  inputchip.pinMode(0xFFFF);     // Use word-write mode to set all of the pins on inputchip to be inputs
  //inputchip.pullupMode(0xFFFF);  // Use word-write mode to Turn on the internal pull-up resistors.
  inputchip.inputInvert(0xFFFF); // Use word-write mode to invert the inputs so that logic 0 is read as HIGH
  outputchip.pinMode(0x0000);    // Use word-write mode to Set all of the pins on outputchip to be outputs
}

void loop() {
  int value;                        // declare an integer to hold the value temporarily.
  value = inputchip.digitalRead();  // read the input chip in word-mode, storing the result in "value"
  outputchip.digitalWrite(value);   // write the output chip in word-mode, using our variable "value" as the argument
  // outputchip.digitalWrite(inputchip.digitalRead()); // this one line replaces the three above, and is more efficient
}
```

I have tried:

- slowing the SPI bus by changing the library to SPI_Divide the clock by 2
- changing the ss line and even splitting the lines so one chip uses pin 10 and the other uses pin 9

So after reading Mr. Gammon's post I have made some changes to the code attempting to rid myself ***of the old slave select pin low trick*** he mentioned. Here is my attempt:

```
MCP inputchip(1, 10);             // Instantiate an object called "inputchip" on an MCP23S17 device at address 1
                                  // and slave-select on Arduino pin 10
MCP outputchip(2, 9);            // Instantiate an object called "outputchip" on an MCP23S17 device at address 2
                                  // and slave-select on Arduino pin 10
int ssPin = 9;

void setup() {
  pinMode(ssPin,OUTPUT);

  inputchip.begin();
  digitalWrite(ssPin, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ssPin, LOW);
  outputchip.begin();
  inputchip.pinMode(0xFFFF);     // Use word-write mode to set all of the pins on inputchip to be inputs
  //inputchip.pullupMode(0xFFFF);  // Use word-write mode to Turn on the internal pull-up resistors.
  inputchip.inputInvert(0xFFFF); // Use word-write mode to invert the inputs so that logic 0 is read as HIGH
  digitalWrite(ssPin, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ssPin, LOW);
  outputchip.pinMode(0x0000);    // Use word-write mode to Set all of the pins on outputchip to be outputs
}

void loop() {
  int value;
  // declare an integer to hold the value temporarily.
  value = inputchip.digitalRead();  // read the input chip in word-mode, storing the result in "value"
  digitalWrite(ssPin, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ssPin, LOW);
  outputchip.digitalWrite(value);   // write the output chip in word-mode, using our variable "value" as the argument
}
```

So any advice would be great to get this working. Help me Obi wan Gammon your me only hope.

Comment: Try my library instead. That one looks horrible. https://github.com/MajenkoLibraries/MCP23S17

Comment: I agree with Majenco...that one looks hard...I am no expert but i used the Adafruit library and found it very friendly... https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-MCP23017-Arduino-Library

Comment: I will try yours now Mr. Majenko. Doug the library you posted is for the I2C version of the chip. I have worked with it  before and found it excellent but must use the SPI for some applications.

Comment: I have one question. Once you set the PinMode of an expander then can you change the mode without giving a reset? I mean, I have to use 3 expanders for controlling an SRAM: on one MCP I have the data lines, on the second one I have the control signals and on the last one I have the address lines. Firstly, I do a SRAM_WRITE, so I need the pins of the first expander to be OUTPUTs,then I do a READ_SRAM so a need the pins of the first expander to be INPUTs. Can I change the mode from output to input? Then I am trying to check the signals with an oscilloscope. When a do a pinMode OUTPUT of the expa

Answer (score 2):

Majenko's library works. All praise to Majenko https://github.com/MajenkoLibraries/MCP23S17

Comment: Nick is only a Demi-god :P I am Zeus and Odin rolled into one. Maybe I should change my name to Zein ... or Odus...? ;)

Answer (score 2):

This sketch uses the [Majenko Library](https://github.com/MajenkoLibraries/MCP23S17) with two MCP23S17 chips to demonstrate the library functions.

It was tested on an Arduino Uno with IDE 1.6.5.

```
/*
 * MultiTest_Majenko_02.ino
 * Library Ref: github.com/MajenkoLibraries/MCP23S17
 * 
 * Lowell Bahner
 * 2016-12-11
 *
 * Hardware: Arduino UNO
 * IDE: Arduino 1.6.5
 * 
 * Useful SPI Ref: gammon.com.au/spi
 * 
 * Wire the SPI Interface common lines (Mega2560 SPI pins shown in [ ]):
 * Arduino SPI_MOSI pin 11 [51] <->   SI  MCP23S17 pin 13
 * Arduino SPI_MISO pin 12 [50] <->   SO  MCP23S17 pin 14
 * Arduino SPI_CLOCK pin 13 [52]<->   SCK MCP23S17 pin 12
 * Arduino SPI_CS pin 10 [53]   <->   SS  MCP23S17 pin 11
 * MCP23S17 VDD pin 9 to +5V
 * MCP23S17 VSS pin 10 to Gnd
 * MCP23S17 Reset pin 18 to +5V 
 * MCP23S17 Interrupt pins 19-20
 * MCP23S17 A0,A1,A2 pins connect to Gnd or +5V (000 = Address 0, 100 = Address 1, 010 = Address 2, etc)
 * MCP23S17 Port A pins are chip pins 21-28
 * MCP23S17 Port B pins are chip pins 1-8
 * 
 * This sketch runs a series of functions to demonstrate library capabilities.
 * This sketch does not demonstrate interrupt functionality.
 *  
 * This sketch instantiates 2 MCP23S17 chips.
 * Bank2 (MCP23S17 address 1) pins are set as INPUT or INPUT_PULLUP.
 *    Normally HIGH, use switch to set a pin LOW.
 * Bank1 (MCP23S17 address 0) pins are set as OUTPUT.
 *    MCP23S17 outputs will power LEDs up to 25ma through 1000ohm resistor to ground.
 *
 * Majenko MCP23S17 library functions (see .h,.cpp files for details):
 *
 *  bank.pinMode(uint8_t pin, uint8_t mode)
 *    where modes are:
 *      OUTPUT - sets pin HIGH
 *      INPUT  - sets pin LOW for sensing change to HIGH +V
 *      INPUT_PULLUP - sets pin HIGH for sensing change to LOW 0V
 *
 *  bank.digitalWrite(uint8_t pin, uint8_t value)
 *    if mode=OUTPUT, pin value = LOW (0) or HIGH (1)
 *    if mode=INPUT, value LOW disables pullup on pin, value HIGH enables pullup on pin
 *
 *  uint8_t value = bank.digitalRead(uint8_t pin)
 *    read the state of the pin
 *
 *  uint8_t value = bank.readPort(uint8_t port)
 *    read entire 8-bit port of all INPUT pins on Port A (port=0) or Port B (port>=1)
 *
 *  uint16_t longValue = bank.readPort()
 *    read both ports as 16-bit combined
 *
 *  bank.writePort(uint8_t port, uint8_t val)
 *    write val (0 or 1, hex example 0x55) to all OUTPUT pins on Port A (port=0) or Port B (port>=1)
 *
 *  bank.writePort(uint16_t val)
 *    write val (hex example 0x55AA) to all OUTPUT pins on Port A and Port B
 *
 *  Also, interrupt functions are defined:
 *      enableInterrupt(uint8_t pin, uint8_t type);
 *      void disableInterrupt(uint8_t pin);
 *      void setMirror(boolean m);
 *      uint16_t getInterruptPins();
 *      uint16_t getInterruptValue();
 *      void setInterruptLevel(uint8_t level);
 *      void setInterruptOD(boolean openDrain);
 *
 *
 *
 *
Run Sketch: Serial Monitor Output

 -- RWpins() --

Bank2: Switch i15: 1 (Push button switch not pushed, Bank2 INPUT pin 15 is HIGH +5V)
Bank1: Output j4:  1 (Bank1 OUTPUT pin 4 is HIGH.
                      Arduino pin 7 is set HIGH.
                      LED on pin 4 is ON. LED on pin 7 is ON.)

Bank2: Switch i15: 0 (Push button switch pushed, grounds Bank2 INPUT pin 15)
Bank1: Output j4:  0 (Bank1 OUTPUT pin 4 switches to LOW.
                      Arduino pin 7 is set LOW.
                      LED on pin 4 is OFF. LED on pin 7 is OFF.)

 -- RWport() --

Bank1: Port A BIN: 00000000
Bank1: Port B BIN: 00000000

Bank1: Port A BIN: 11110100  DEC: 244
Bank1: Port B BIN: 00001011  DEC: 11

 -- RWlongPortValue() --

Bank1: Port A & B BIN: 0000101111110100  HEX: 0x0BF4    DEC: 3060

 -- RWlongPort() --

Bank1: Port A & B BIN: 1011100101000010  HEX: 0xB942    DEC: 47426

 -- CyclePins() --

Bank1: Port A & B BIN: 0000000000000000  HEX: 0x0000    DEC: 0
Bank1: Port A & B BIN: 0000000000000001  HEX: 0x0001    DEC: 1
Bank1: Port A & B BIN: 0000000000000011  HEX: 0x0003    DEC: 3
Bank1: Port A & B BIN: 0000000000000111  HEX: 0x0007    DEC: 7
Bank1: Port A & B BIN: 0000000000001111  HEX: 0x000F    DEC: 15
Bank1: Port A & B BIN: 0000000000011111  HEX: 0x001F    DEC: 31
Bank1: Port A & B BIN: 0000000000111111  HEX: 0x003F    DEC: 63
Bank1: Port A & B BIN: 0000000001111111  HEX: 0x007F    DEC: 127
Bank1: Port A & B BIN: 0000000011111111  HEX: 0x00FF    DEC: 255
Bank1: Port A & B BIN: 0000000111111111  HEX: 0x01FF    DEC: 511
Bank1: Port A & B BIN: 0000001111111111  HEX: 0x03FF    DEC: 1023
Bank1: Port A & B BIN: 0000011111111111  HEX: 0x07FF    DEC: 2047
Bank1: Port A & B BIN: 0000111111111111  HEX: 0x0FFF    DEC: 4095
Bank1: Port A & B BIN: 0001111111111111  HEX: 0x1FFF    DEC: 8191
Bank1: Port A & B BIN: 0011111111111111  HEX: 0x3FFF    DEC: 16383
Bank1: Port A & B BIN: 0111111111111111  HEX: 0x7FFF    DEC: 32767
Bank1: Port A & B BIN: 1111111111111111  HEX: 0xFFFF    DEC: 65535

Bank1: Port A & B BIN: 1111111111111111  HEX: 0xFFFF    DEC: 65535
Bank1: Port A & B BIN: 0111111111111111  HEX: 0x7FFF    DEC: 32767
Bank1: Port A & B BIN: 0011111111111111  HEX: 0x3FFF    DEC: 16383
Bank1: Port A & B BIN: 0001111111111111  HEX: 0x1FFF    DEC: 8191
Bank1: Port A & B BIN: 0000111111111111  HEX: 0x0FFF    DEC: 4095
Bank1: Port A & B BIN: 0000011111111111  HEX: 0x07FF    DEC: 2047
Bank1: Port A & B BIN: 0000001111111111  HEX: 0x03FF    DEC: 1023
Bank1: Port A & B BIN: 0000000111111111  HEX: 0x01FF    DEC: 511
Bank1: Port A & B BIN: 0000000011111111  HEX: 0x00FF    DEC: 255
Bank1: Port A & B BIN: 0000000001111111  HEX: 0x007F    DEC: 127
Bank1: Port A & B BIN: 0000000000111111  HEX: 0x003F    DEC: 63
Bank1: Port A & B BIN: 0000000000011111  HEX: 0x001F    DEC: 31
Bank1: Port A & B BIN: 0000000000001111  HEX: 0x000F    DEC: 15
Bank1: Port A & B BIN: 0000000000000111  HEX: 0x0007    DEC: 7
Bank1: Port A & B BIN: 0000000000000011  HEX: 0x0003    DEC: 3
Bank1: Port A & B BIN: 0000000000000001  HEX: 0x0001    DEC: 1
Bank1: Port A & B BIN: 0000000000000000  HEX: 0x0000    DEC: 0
 *
 *
 *
 */

// Majenko MCP23S17 Library
#include <MCP23S17.h>

// Arduino Library SPI.h
#include <SPI.h>

// SPI CS/SS chipselect pin can be changed by user as desired
const uint8_t chipSelect = 10;

// example Arduino board pin
uint8_t pin7 = 7;

// Create an object for each chip
// Bank1 is address 0. Pins A0,A1,A2 grounded.
// Bank2 is address 1. Pin A0=+5V, A1,A2 grounded.

MCP23S17 Bank1(&SPI, chipSelect, 0);
MCP23S17 Bank2(&SPI, chipSelect, 1);

void setup() {

  // Slow down the master a bit if desired
  SPI.setClockDivider(SPI_CLOCK_DIV8);

  Serial.begin(9600);

  Bank1.begin();
  Bank2.begin();

  // LED connected to Arduino pin 7 to test inter-device communication
  pinMode(pin7, OUTPUT);

  //
  // Set MCP23S17 pin modes:
  // example set one pin: chip.pinMode(0, OUTPUT); // sets chip pin 0 (Port A 0) to OUTPUT mode
  //
  // setChipPins(); // use loop to set individual pins
  // or, since this library does not have a setPortPinMode, do 8 pin loops
  setPortPins(); // example: set pins on each Port on each chip to different modes.
  //

}

// Set all Chip pins to desired mode
void setChipPins() {
  // Example usage

  // Set all Bank1 pins to be OUTPUT
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i <= 15; i++)
    Bank1.pinMode(i, OUTPUT);

  // Set all Bank2 pins to be INPUT_PULLUP
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i <= 15; i++)
    //Bank2.pinMode(i, INPUT);  // unswitched pin voltages about +0.1V, switch must pull pin to +5V
    Bank2.pinMode(i, INPUT_PULLUP);  // unswitched pin voltages about +4.9V, switch must ground pin
}

// Set Port pins to desired mode
void setPortPins() {
  // Example usage

  // Set all Bank1 Port A pins to OUTPUT
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i <= 7; i++)
    Bank1.pinMode(i, OUTPUT);

  // Set all Bank1 Port B pins to OUTPUT
  for (uint8_t i = 8; i <= 15; i++)
    Bank1.pinMode(i, OUTPUT);

  // Set all Bank2 Port A pins to be INPUT
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i <= 7; i++)
    Bank2.pinMode(i, INPUT);

  // Set all Bank2 Port B pins to be INPUT_PULLUP
  for (uint8_t i = 8; i <= 15; i++)
    Bank2.pinMode(i, INPUT_PULLUP);
}


//
// Change LED On/Off with button push
// 1) Switch an INPUT_PULLUP pin to ground
// 2) Read the pin value
// 3) Write the value to an OUTPUT pin
// 4) Turn LED On/Off
// Use functions digitalRead(pin) and digitalWrite(pin,value)
//
void RWpins() {

  Serial.print("\n -- RWpins() --"); Serial.println("");

  uint8_t b15 = 0;  // Bank2 input pin value (0 push LOW, 1 normally open HIGH) with push button switch to gnd
  uint8_t i = 15;   // Bank2 pin number
  uint8_t a4 = 0;   // Bank1 output pin value
  uint8_t j = 4;    // Bank1 pin number

  // read the switch value into b15
  b15 = Bank2.digitalRead(i);
  Serial.print("\nBank2: Switch i"); Serial.print(i); Serial.print(": ");  Serial.println(b15);

  // write the switch pin i, value b15, to the output pin j
  Bank1.digitalWrite(j, b15);

  a4 = Bank1.digitalRead(j);
  Serial.print("Bank1: Output j"); Serial.print(j); Serial.print(": ");  Serial.println(a4);

  // Turn on/off LED connected to Arduino pin 7 through resistor to ground
  digitalWrite(pin7, a4);
}


//
// Read and Write Port values
//
void RWport() {

  Serial.print("\n -- RWport() --"); Serial.println("");

  // set the port pin modes
  setPortPins(); // all Bank1 pins are OUTPUT but set as Ports

  // clear the port pin values to 0
  uint8_t port = 0; // Port A
  uint8_t val = 0x00; // set to 0000 0000
  Bank1.writePort(port, val);
  port = 1; // Port B
  Bank1.writePort(port, val); // set to 0000 0000

  // read the port pin values
  uint8_t valueA = Bank1.readPort(0);
  Serial.print("\nBank1: Port A BIN: "); print8Bits(valueA); Serial.println("");
  uint8_t valueB = Bank1.readPort(1);
  Serial.print("Bank1: Port B BIN: "); print8Bits(valueB); Serial.println("");

  // set the port pin values
  port = 0; // Port A
  val = 0xF4; // set to 1111 0100
  Bank1.writePort(port, val);
  port = 1; // Port B
  val = 0x0B; // set to 0000 1011
  //val = 0xB0; // set to 1011 0000
  Bank1.writePort(port, val);

  // read the port pin values
  valueA = Bank1.readPort(0);
  Serial.print("\nBank1: Port A BIN: "); print8Bits(valueA);
  Serial.print("  DEC: "); Serial.println(valueA, DEC);

  valueB = Bank1.readPort(1);
  Serial.print("Bank1: Port B BIN: "); print8Bits(valueB);
  Serial.print("  DEC: "); Serial.println(valueB, DEC);
}


void RWlongPortValue() {

  Serial.print("\n -- RWlongPortValue() --"); Serial.println("");

  // Read the Bank1 Port pin values as a combined long value
  uint16_t valueLong = Bank1.readPort();
  Serial.print("\nBank1: Port A & B BIN: "); print16Bits(valueLong);
  Serial.print("  HEX: "); crPrintHEX(valueLong, 4);
  Serial.print("  DEC: "); Serial.println(valueLong, DEC);
}


void RWlongPort() {

  Serial.print("\n -- RWlongPort() --"); Serial.println("");

  // Write the Bank1 Port pin values as a combined long value
  uint16_t valueLong = 0xB942;
  Bank1.writePort(valueLong);

  // Read the Bank1 Port pin values as a combined long value
  uint16_t valueLongIn = Bank1.readPort();
  Serial.print("\nBank1: Port A & B BIN: "); print16Bits(valueLongIn);
  Serial.print("  HEX: "); crPrintHEX(valueLongIn, 4);
  Serial.print("  DEC: "); Serial.println(valueLongIn, DEC);
}


//
// Cycle through OUTPUT pins with count-up count-down
//
void CyclePins() {

  Serial.print("\n -- CyclePins() --"); Serial.println("\n");

  // Set all Bank1 pins to be OUTPUT
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i <= 15; i++)
    Bank1.pinMode(i, OUTPUT);

  // clear Bank1 using writePort
  uint16_t valueLong = 0x0000;
  Bank1.writePort(valueLong);

  // Read the Bank1 Port pin values as a combined long value
  for (int8_t i = -1; i <= 15; i++) {
    if (i >= 0) Bank1.digitalWrite(i, 1); // i=-1 allows print of 0 data
    valueLong = Bank1.readPort(); // read 16 bits
    Serial.print("Bank1: Port A & B BIN: "); print16Bits(valueLong);
    Serial.print("  HEX: "); crPrintHEX(valueLong, 4);
    Serial.print("  DEC: "); Serial.println(valueLong, DEC);
  }

  Serial.println("");

  for (int8_t i = 15; i >= -1; i--) { // i=-1 allows print of 0 data
    // decrement after the read while reading down the values
    valueLong = Bank1.readPort(); //  read 16 bits
    Serial.print("Bank1: Port A & B BIN: "); print16Bits(valueLong);
    Serial.print("  HEX: "); crPrintHEX(valueLong, 4);
    Serial.print("  DEC: "); Serial.println(valueLong, DEC);
    Bank1.digitalWrite(i, 0);
  }
}


void loop() {

  // Change LED On/Off with button push
  RWpins();

  // Read and Write Port pins as a group
  RWport();

  // Read the Bank1 Port pin values as a combined long value
  RWlongPortValue();

  // Read and Write Chip 16 pins as a group
  RWlongPort();

  // Cycle through OUTPUT pins with count-up count-down
  CyclePins();

  delay(1000);

}

// print 8-bit byte as 8 bit binary string
void print8Bits(uint8_t myByte) {
  for (byte mask = 0x80; mask; mask >>= 1) {
    if (mask  & myByte)
      Serial.print('1');
    else
      Serial.print('0');
  }
}

// print 16-bit word as 16 bit binary string
void print16Bits(uint16_t myWord) {
  for (uint16_t mask = 0x8000; mask; mask >>= 1) {
    if (mask  & myWord)
      Serial.print('1');
    else
      Serial.print('0');
  }
}


//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// crPrintHEX print value as hex with specified number of digits
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void crPrintHEX(unsigned long DATA, unsigned char numChars) {
  unsigned long mask  = 0x0000000F;
  mask = mask << 4 * (numChars - 1);
  Serial.print("0x");
  for (unsigned int i = numChars; i > 0; --i) {
    Serial.print(((DATA & mask) >> (i - 1) * 4), HEX);
    mask = mask >> 4;
  }

  Serial.print("  ");
}
```